# Include link from Facebook to AppStore / App Page

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an IOS app that posts videos to the users and their friends walls using:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"Video.mp4",
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               @"My Title", @"title",
                               @"Description", @"description",
                               nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){ ...
```

This is working flawlessly but I would now link to make a link from this post to the AppStore and the App page on Facebook. I have tried this with some HTML but it just displays it in plain text.

As suggested elsewhere I have added the 'link' property and tried 'properties' but these do not appear to add anything to the wall post. It looks like they only work with Feeds and not wall posts.

Can anyone advise a way (or better overall way) of displaying these link without just putting the full "http://itunes.appl......"